# Adding operations in NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsoperationqueue

I am starting out on NSOperationQueue in iOS and facing some basic issues which I would like to clarify.

This is the code I am using:

```
-(void) SendRequestWithURL:(NSString*) URL andParam:(id) attributes {

    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] incrementActivityCount];
    _m_singleton = [Singleton sharedSingleton];
    _parser = [[Syncparser alloc]init];
    NSString *strServURL  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_m_singleton.globalstrURLLink,URL];
    if (_theService == Item0 || _theService == Item1 || _theService == Item2){
        NSLog(@"Entrance _theService  %i", _theService);

    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strServURL]];
    [client postPath:@"POST" parameters:attributes
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 NSLog(@"_theService  %i", _theService);
                 switch (_theService) {
                     case Item0: {
                         [_m_singleton.globalQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
                             NSLog(@"ParseItem0  %@", [operation responseString]);
                             [_parser ParseItem0:[operation responseString]];
                         }];
                     }
                         break;
                     case Item1:{
                         [_m_singleton.globalQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
                             NSLog(@"ParseItem1  %@", [operation responseString]);
                             [_parser ParseItem1:[operation responseString]];
                         }];
                     }
                         break;
                     case Item2:{
                         [_m_singleton.globalQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
                             NSLog(@"ParseItem2  %@", [operation responseString]);
                             [_parser ParseItem2:[operation responseString]];
                         }];
                     }
                         break;
                     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    }
}
```

I only called item1 and item2.These are the values I get in the debugger.

```
Entrance _theService  1
Entrance _theService  2
_theService  2
_theService  1
```

This clearly means that the item2 gets added to the queue first and followed by item1.

But surprisingly, ParseItem1 gets called before ParseItem2 everytime. Even if _theService  1 comes before _theService  2.  Not sure why. Sorry for the noob question.

Need some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the priority of the NSOperation that you are adding? 
The following are the possible values for the NSOperation priority property:
 - NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryLow
 - NSOperationQueuePriorityLow
 - NSOperationQueuePriorityNormal
 - NSOperationQueuePriorityHigh
 - NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryHigh

You might also want to set the maxConcurrentOperationCount property to 1 if you want it to process one operation at a time.

Another is you can set the dependency property of an NSOperation of _theService1 with the value _theService2 so that _theService2 will have to wait for _theService1 to finish before it executes.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but why does it always start with _theService1 if no dependency is set? my question is why is always fixed to _theService1. based on the logic, whichever _theService get printed first should get executed first.

Comment: Two things worth noting about maxConcurrentOperationCount from the docs:  "The specified value affects only the receiver and the operations in its queue. Other operation queue objects can also execute their maximum number of operations in parallel.

Reducing the number of concurrent operations does not affect any operations that are currently executing. If you specify the value NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount (which is recommended), the maximum number of operations can change dynamically based on system conditions."

Answer (score 0):

> This clearly means that the item2 gets added to the queue first and
>   followed by item1.

This assumption is wrong.  NSOperationQueue, used by AFNetworking, does not guarantee that the operations will be started or finished in the order you add them.  In face, in AFHTTPClient's init method, you can see:

```
self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[self.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount];
```

So your queue is going to be executing operations concurrently for sure.

I can't say why this reverse call is always happening in your testing, but I assume the second call is either faster to return, or faster to parse, or both.

Anyway, if you need both operations to return to parse successfully, you can use `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock:` and the completion block won't get called until they're all done.  Or you can set one operation to be dependant on another (since it's an NSOperation subclass.)